# Write 7. as 7.0 and .7 as 0.7

Tags: functions

i would like to know how to do in order to transform using a function .7 in 0.7 and 7 in 7.0. I need that the values in the list will really change because i must print them in a text file.

Thank you.

Comment: Export them as strings ? Plus, you are not really giving us any details about the problems you are encountering. Post any relevant code.

Comment: Check `{NumberForm[ 7., {1, 1}], NumberForm[0.7, {1, 1}]}`.

Comment: Similarly, try `NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 1}] & /@ {7., .7}`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to display a number in a specific way.

Some of them, with examples:

- `EngineeringForm[10000.]` = 10.x10^3
- `ScientificForm[10000.]` = 1.x10^4
- `NumberForm[10000., {7, 1}]`= 10000.0
- And some special as `AccountingForm` that use accounting notation featuring e.g. a special notation of negative numbers.

NumberForm seems most relevant for you, as pointed out by Sungmin. It lets you specify a display style with using a specified number of precise digits (we call them PD now) and a number of digits right of the decimal (DD).
Use is:

- `NumberForm[YourNumber,{PD,DD}]`

In your case

- `NumberForm[ 7., {1, 1}]` = 7.0
- `NumberForm[.7, {1, 1}]` = 0.7

One general remark concerning the number of precise digits (also called significant figures): The number of precise digits of a multiplication/division can not increase above the lowest number of precise digits of all variables involved. Similar holds for addition/subtraction. Thats why rounding should be done at the very end of calculations and be avoided in between.